# How to use external images in webpack

Tags: webpack

I'm currently doing an api test locally, I need to get an external image from 'https://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com/example.jpg ' but I can't.
It doesn't render normally on the screen

I'm using webpack5 and I set it up as follows.

`webpack.common.js`

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { ProvidePlugin } = require('webpack');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: './src/index.tsx',
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    clean: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/index.html'),
    }),
    new Dotenv(),
    new ProvidePlugin({
      React: 'react',
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.jsx', '.js'],
    alias: {
      '@components': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components'),
      '@styles': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/styles'),
      '@apis': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/apis'),
      '@assets': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets'),
      '@pages': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/pages'),
      '@constants': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/constants'),
      '@context': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/context'),
      '@hooks': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/hooks'),
      '@utils': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/utils'),
      '@atoms': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/atoms'),
      '@public': path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
      '@config': path.resolve(__dirname, 'config.ts'),
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|webp)$/,
        type: 'asset',
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: ['@svgr/webpack', 'url-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)?$/,
        type: 'asset',
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

`webpack.dev.js`

```
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    open: true,
    hot: true,
    port: 3000,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
});
```

What additional settings do I need in webpack5 to use external images?